# Group similar values in first column and join its second column value using delimiter in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Ive an SQL table looks like this

```
 ID      |     Pattern
 ---------------------
 1       |     2345
 2       |     3345
 3       |     2345
 4       |     5647
 5       |     1472
 6       |     4817
 7       |     5871
 8       |     2345
 9       |     5871
 10      |     1472
```

Here the pattern is just some random patterns. But I need a kinda grouping based on that pattern. So the output should be something like this

```
 Pattern     |    ConnectedIDs
 -----------------------------
 2345        |    1,3,8
 3345        |    2
 5647        |    4
 1472        |    5,10
 4817        |    6
 5871        |    7,9
-----------------------------------------
```

Hope you got the scenario..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this (**[Fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/5ff18/2)**):

```
SELECT t1.Pattern,  
       Ids = REPLACE( (SELECT Id AS [data()]
             FROM Table1 t2
             WHERE t2.Pattern = t1.Pattern
             ORDER BY t2.Pattern
             FOR XML PATH('')
            ), ' ', ',')
FROM Table1 t1
GROUP BY Pattern;
```

Results:

```
| PATTERN |   IDS |
|---------|-------|
|    1472 |  5,10 |
|    2345 | 1,3,8 |
|    3345 |     2 |
|    4817 |     6 |
|    5647 |     4 |
|    5871 |   7,9 |
```

Comment: Thanks boss.. thats awesome.. thats exactly what am looking for... cheers

Answer (score 0):

You could use this scalar valued function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[GetPatternIDs]
(
    @pattern varchar(4),
    @delimiter varchar(4)
)
RETURNS VARCHAR(8000)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @IDs VARCHAR(8000) 
    SELECT @IDs = COALESCE(@IDs + @delimiter, '') +  CAST(Patterns.ID AS VARCHAR(10))
    FROM  Patterns
    WHERE Pattern=@pattern
    ORDER By Patterns.ID
    RETURN @IDs
END
```

and this query:

```
SELECT Pattern, 
       ConnectedIDs = dbo.GetPatternIDs(Pattern, ',')
FROM Patterns 
GROUP BY Pattern
ORDER BY MIN(ID)
```

<kbd>[**DEMO**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/16762/13/0)</kbd>

Comment: I tried with a similar function before. But when tons of rows this is a little slow.. but the above right answer is nice.. thanks